# React Native pass function to child component as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native (and React), and I'm trying to pass a function as a prop to a component.

My goal is to create a component where its onPress functionality can be set by the instantiator of the component, so that it is more reusable.

Here is my code so far.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import TouchableButton from './components/touchable-button';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  handlePress () {
    // this should be called when my custom component is clicked
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableButton handlePress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

TouchableButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import AppButton from "./app-button";

export default class TouchableButton extends Component {
  handlePress;

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={
        this.props.handlePress
      }>
        <AppButton/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

I am passing the handlePress function as the prop handlePress. I would expect the TouchableButton's props to contain that function, however it isn't there.

Comment: What is handlePress doing on line 6 in your second component?

Comment: What is being console.logged when you console.log(this.props) inside the render method of the second component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When writing `handlePress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}` you passing a statement execution ( which when and if executed returns a function). What is expected is to pass the function itself either with `handlePress={this.handlePress}` (and do the binding in the constructor) or `handlePress={() => this.handlePress()}` which passes an anonymous function which when executed will execute handlePress in `this` class context.

Comment: @Jerred is using a regular function when creating handlePress method, so passing this.handlePress.bind(this) when handlePress is a regular function is the same as passing this.handlePress when handlePress is an arrow function.

Comment: Almost the same the first is an expression which should be executed to get a function. The second is the function object itself.

Answer (score 10):

## Solution

Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for no care about binding `this`.

And I recommend to check null before calling the props method.

App.js

```js
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    // Do what you want. 
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableButton onPress={this.handlePress}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

TouchableButton.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import AppButton from "./app-button";

export default class TouchableButton extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  
  handlePress = () => {
    // Need to check to prevent null exception. 
    this.props.onPress?.(); // Same as this.props.onPress && this.props.onPress();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handlePress}>
        <AppButton/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Jeff, I'm trying to use your solution but I get this error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.getParam") , Do you have any idea what should I do?

Comment: @Niloufar Hello. I think it is the problem related to your `react-navigation`. If you make a new question including your code, Leave the link here. I will help you.

Comment: Thanks. here is my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412797/navigation-getparam-is-undefined-while-trying-to-pass-function-as-parameter

Answer (score 4):

```
// Parent

handleClick( name ){
   alert(name);
}

<Child func={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />

// Children

let { func } = this.props;

func( 'VARIABLE' );
```