# React Native get parent of components

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and I have a component inside a component.

I need to access a function of the parent from the child component. How do I access the parent, e.g. something like `this.parentNode.myFunc();` from the child? (of course, without passing it as a prop down the whole view hierarchy)

Comment: please share code in which you have used child component.

Comment: pass the function to the component by props.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547751/react-native-pass-function-to-child-component-as-prop

Comment: @NaeimFard that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, as I've stated in the question.

Comment: do you have large list of function to be called from child ? that why you want to avoid this method

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Try using ```Context API```, and then ```consume``` the required function wherever you want to down the hierarchy.

Comment: @JaydeepGalani I might, even if not now. It's not about the functions, it's about passing down a whole bunch of props down a complex hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Send to child component as props. Like that:

```
<ChildComponent myProp={this.myFunc} />
```

and then, you can call the function `this.props.myProp()`

Comment: I can pass props, but I might have a complex view hierarchy. I'd like to do it without passing down props down the tree (I've updated my question)

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Use Contex API

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass the callback as a prop or you can create a Provider-Consumer ([Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)) if you don't want to drill down.

Answer (score 0):

Please bind function in parent component and pass to child component.

Here is my function in Parent.js component

```
testFunction() {
    console.log('Test')
  }
```

Bind in constructor :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.testFunction = this.testFunction.bind(this)
  }
```

Pass this to child component :

```
<Child testFunction = {this.testFunction}>
```

Use this in child component with props in Child.js component:

```
this.props.testFunction()
```