# How do i pass the value in counter component to the add to the To Cart Button

Tags: react-native

Hi I have a add minus component button that I want to pass the value to selected value to the "To Cart" button. If the value is zero the orders will not be added but if the value is > 0 then it will be added to cart.

below is my Add Minus button component

1. AddMinusButton.js

   ```
   import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

    import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";

    const AddMinusButton = () => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

      const minusValue = () => {
        if (value > 0) {
          setValue(value - 1);
        } else {
          setValue(0);
        }
      };

      const plusValue = () => {
        setValue(value + 1);
      };

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonLeft} onPress={minusValue}>
            <Text>-</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.quantity}> {value}</Text>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonRight} onPress={plusValue}>
            <Text>+</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        height: 35,
        overflow: "hidden",
        borderColor: "black",
      },
      quantity: {
        paddingHorizontal: 10,

        marginRight: 3,
      },

      buttonLeft: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
        borderRightWidth: 1,
        borderRightColor: "black",
        padding: 10,
      },

      buttonRight: {
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
        borderLeftWidth: 1,
        borderLeftColor: "black",
        padding: 10,
      },
    });

    export default AddMinusButton;
   ```
2. This is my Product Screen. I want to pass the value that is selected by the AddMinusButton component to the "To Cart". I am only able to made the button click and it will add one by one.

ProductOverviewScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  Platform,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";

import HeaderButton from "../../components/UI/HeaderButton";
import ProductItem from "../../components/shop/ProductItem";
import * as cartActions from "../../store/actions/cart";
import * as productsActions from "../../store/actions/products";

import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";
import * as AddMinusButton from "../../components/UI/AddMinusButton";

const ProductsOverviewScreen = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.availableProducts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const loadProducts = useCallback(async () => {
    setError(null);
    setIsRefreshing(true);
    try {
      await dispatch(productsActions.fetchProducts());
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
    setIsRefreshing(false);
  }, [dispatch, setIsLoading, setError]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const willFocusSub = props.navigation.addListener(
      "willFocus",
      loadProducts
    );

    return () => {
      willFocusSub.remove();
    };
  }, [loadProducts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    loadProducts().then(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [dispatch, loadProducts]);

  const selectItemHandler = (id, title) => {
    props.navigation.navigate("ProductDetail", {
      productId: id,
      productTitle: title,
    });
  };

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.centered}>
        <Text>An error occurred!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Try again"
          onPress={loadProducts}
          color={Colors.primary}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.centered}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.primary} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (!isLoading && products.length === 0) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.centered}>
        <Text>No products found. Maybe start adding some!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      onRefresh={loadProducts}
      refreshing={isRefreshing}
      data={products}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={(itemData) => (
        <ProductItem
          image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
          title={itemData.item.title}
          price={itemData.item.price}
          onSelect={() => {
            selectItemHandler(itemData.item.id, itemData.item.title);
          }}
        >
          <AddMinusButton />

          <Button
            color={Colors.primary}
            title="To Cart"
            onPress={() => {
              dispatch(cartActions.addToCart(itemData.item));
            }}
          />
        </ProductItem>
      )}
    />
  );
};

ProductsOverviewScreen.navigationOptions = (navData) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: "All Products",
    headerLeft: (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Menu"
          iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-menu" : "ios-menu"}
          onPress={() => {
            navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    ),
    headerRight: (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Cart"
          iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-cart" : "ios-cart"}
          onPress={() => {
            navData.navigation.navigate("Cart");
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    ),
  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centered: { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" },
});

export default ProductsOverviewScreen;
```

Comment: Send a method to the button component as a prop and get the data in your parent component.

Comment: is there an example or a tutorial i can refer to?

Comment: You can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547751/react-native-pass-function-to-child-component-as-prop

Comment: i did some read up and i still can't get it. I am new to coding though sorry. Can i use reducer in my AddMinusButton because the output of the value is variable?

Comment: I could not get your question. All you have to do is create a function in your parent component and pass that to your child component like this
<Child customFunction={customFuction} />
and you can access that in Child component using props.customFuction()